# How to lazy load views using ui-router and requirejs

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, angular-ui-router

I would to use https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router with http://requirejs.org/ and load views only when they are needed. I have found the following example: https://github.com/ifyio/angularjs-lazy-loading-with-requirejs which works great with angular-route (ngRoute). I have been trying to make it work with angular-ui-router without success so far. Please help me to figure out the issue.

*route-states-config.js:*

```
define([], function()
{
    return {
        states: {
            "index": {
                url: "/",
                views: {
                    "topMenu": {
                        templateUrl: "/Home/TopMenu",
```

**I would like to have something like this:**

```
                        dependencies: [
                            "controllers/top-menu-controller"
                        ],
```

**instead of:**

```
                        controller: 'TopMenuCtrl'
```

**because in this case I have to load the controller always**

```
                    },
                    "leftMenu": {
                        templateUrl: "/Home/LeftMenu",
                        dependencies: [
                            "controllers/left-menu-controller"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
});
```

*// dependencyResolverFor.js:*

```
define([], function() {
    return function(dependencies) {
        var definition = {
            resolver: ['$q', '$rootScope', function($q, $rootScope) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                require(dependencies, function() {
                    $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                        deferred.resolve();
                    });
                });

                return deferred.promise;
            }]
        };

        return definition;
    };
});
```

// app.js

```
define(['route-states-config', 'services/dependencyResolverFor'], function(config, dependencyResolverFor) {

    var app= angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);

    app.config(function($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

        if (config.states !== undefined) {
```

**here I need to resolve the dependencies from route-states-config.js somehow:**

```
            angular.forEach(config.states, function (state, stateName) {
                angular.forEach(state.views, function (view, viewName) {

                });

                $stateProvider.state(stateName, state);

                // taken from the working example which uses ngRoute
                /* $routeProvider.when(path, {templateUrl:route.templateUrl, resolve:dependencyResolverFor(route.dependencies)}); */

            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I made it work with ocLazyLoad: https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad
You can also find tutorial there how to use it with ui-router (in other words, you need to return a promise which will be resolved in resolve property)